# Does Azure Media Services support Java/PHP/Python/RoR?

Tags: azure, media-player, azure-media-services

I'm trying to learn about Azure Media Services, while i gone through the documentation i found  the SDK is only available for .Net but does anyone know the availability of Media Services SDK for other platforms like Java/PHP/Python/RoR?

Answer (score 2):

Looking at various SDKs for Azure on [Github](https://github.com/Azure):

Java - Yes (https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-java/tree/master/media)

Python - No

Ruby - No

PHP - Yes (https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-php/tree/master/WindowsAzure/MediaServices)

Answer (score 0):

This is a Ruby SDK as well, but not officially from my team. 
https://github.com/murayama/azure_media_service_ruby

Answer (score 0):

There is also now a Python implementation that is community built.

```
pip install amspy
```

https://github.com/msleal/amspy